# OrientDB creating edges with Javascript function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, orientdb

Good day,

I have two classes, one representing Hospital Admissions (called Ricoveri) and another one representing Discharges (called Dimissioni). Both have a property named Nosologico, representing an admission's unique identifier.

I have written a Javascript function, inspired by one of Luca Garulli's posts, to recursively create Edges between the two classes on the Nosologico property.

function code is as follows:

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var b=g.command('sql','select from Ricoveri')

for(i=0; i<b.length; i++){

var id=b[i].getProperty("Nosologico").toString();

var rid=b[i].getId().toString();

var r=g.command("sql", "select from Dimissioni where Nosologico = '" + id + "'");

if(r.length>0){  
var sql2="create edge dimesso from " + rid + " to (select from Dimissioni where Nosologico = '" + id + "')";

g.command('sql',sql2);
}
}
```

The function gets created successfully and executes without errors but it doesn't create any Edge.
Occasionally the whole server gets frozen and I have no other option than to kill it and restart it.

Is there anything wrong with the function?

Thanks.
QQ

Comment: I have just noticed this message in the server command window:""" 'Select from Ricoveri' returns a result set with more than 10000 records. Check if you really need all these records, or reduce the resultset by using a LIMIT to improve both performance and used RAM"" 10000 records is far too little for my needs. How can I achieve the same without this limitation?

Comment: HI, is it possible that in Dimissioni class there isn't a record with the same Nosologico that is in Ricoveri? you can try to insert some print("something"); for debugging

Comment: don't worry, that is just a warning, the query is done anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I suggest, if you heaven't done already, to create UNIQUE_HASH_INDEXes on *nosologico* property in both classes.

Then assuming that every *nosologico* in **Dimissioni** is also present in **Ricoveri**, and assuming that there are fewer Dimissioni than Ricoveri, the following query should be more efficient.

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var b=g.command('sql','select from Dimissioni');
var id="";
var rid="";
var sql2="";

for(i=0; i<b.length; i++){

id=b[i].getProperty("Nosologico").toString();

rid=b[i].getId().toString();

sql2="create edge dimesso from (select from Ricoveri where Nosologico = '" + id + "') to " + rid;

g.command('sql',sql2);
g.commit();

}
```

let me know if this helps.

Ivan

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I had already commented on previous reply. Dimissioni and Ricoveri have a one-to-one relation so it should not make any difference. Index already existed on Nosologico property and it is a UNIQUE , not UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX but I don't think that is causing the instability and the wrong results.

Comment: well, this function should be more efficient anyway. please, give it a try. tnx

Comment: btw, hash indexes are fastern i think

Comment: Your function returns this error after creating a 4451 edges...I frankly cannot see what could be wrong with it as it looks correct:   No edge has been created because no source vertices (<Unknown source>#16)\nNo edge has been created because no source vertices". Error messages too aren't reliable..

Comment: Hi Ivan, I have truncated the class Dimesso, updated Ricoveri with REMOVE out_dimesso option and run your script again. This time it worked for all 10798 Ricoveri...Still cannot understand why such unpredictable behavior. Will try to run again similar script for other edges and see how it behaves. In the meantime I have noticed that OrientDB Studio doesn't keep commands history in the new installation...minor problem, annoying though

Comment: It now works on other edges too. It seems like it doesn't like declaring variables recursively in the loop. In your script in fact you simply reassign values to variables declared once, outside the loop. That's the difference I spotted. Nevertheless you solved my problem. Thanks Ivan. (btw, you wouldn't know why my command history is not working?)

Comment: i think the main difference is the g.commit(); at every loop. in this way it doesn't saturate the ram.  (don't know about the history, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

maybe i'm wrong but, you do the query

```
var r=g.command("sql", "select from Ricoveri where Nosologico = '" + id + "'");
```

then you verify the length of the results, but it's pretty obvious that is > 0 (var **id** is coming from var **b** that is coming from the first query on Ricoveri).

So I'm saying, maybe in the var **r** you wanted to query from Dimissioni?

```
var r=g.command("sql", "select from Dimissioni where Nosologico = '" + id + "'");
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, it's a typo. I have actually modified the query from a the original one with more complex and long names. I indeed check for the existence of Dimissioni and not Ricoveri

Comment: I'm try with your corrected function and it works for me. The edges are correctly created

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your support. Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me and often it crashes the server as well. But I am beginning to think that my installation may be faulty. I am also experiencing problems with wrong edges and duplicate edges being created when I run a batch script to create them. Could it be because the server was part of a two server cluster (one is dead)?

Comment: I have started with a fresh install and reimported data using oetl. Yet the server is still completely unreliable and crashes when I run the above javascript function although it reports that Edges were created successfully. Occasionally it succeeds but creates wrong and too few edges. I am using the windows version on a Win 8.1 64bit development machine.

Comment: so you are using distibuted servers, what's your configuration? number of servers, read/write quorum settings (found'em in default-distributed-db-config.json file). There are some issues with distributed right now..

Comment: another question: how much record do you have in your Dimissioni e Ricoveri classes? Tnx

Comment: I have reinstalled a new server, so now is single node only. In my test environment I only have 7069 of type Pazienti and 10798 of classes Ricoveri / Dimissioni. Dimissioni and Ricoveri should have a one-to-one relationship while Pazienti has a one-to-many relationship with Ricoveri. OrientDB version is 2.1.12 but with all previous versions I have always experienced problems of wrong edges being created. In the past I used large query batches to create edges. I was now hoping to have an easier approach using a function. Results though are even worse now.